# Why does my Python Function run only once?

Tags: python, long-integer

I'm currently doing an assignment in which I have to analyze a pickle file, which is essentially a giant list of lists (36,600 lists, and each of them list temperatures for specific dates for either Boston, Chicago, LA, Dallas, or Denver).

The lists' format is:

```
[city, month, day, year, temperature (on this specific date) ]
```

so after importing the pickle and opening this file, I did:

```
import pickle
weather_file = open("Weather Data.pkl","rb")
obj1 = pickle.load(weather_file)
import statistics
```

For example, obj[30000] would print:

```
['Los Angeles', 11, 27, 1996, 65.8]
```

then I did

```
LA_temp = list()
for D in obj1:
    if D[0] == "Los Angeles" and D[1] == 1 and D[3] == 2014:
        LA_temp.append(D[4])
```

LA_temp became a list with 31 elements, which were temperatures of each of the 31 days in January, 2014.

```
55.6, 60.7, 57.2, 56.4, 59.1, 63.5, 61.1, 57.2, 56.2, 56.3, 57.4, 57.9, 62.7, 66.2, 67.8, 68.6, 69.5, 65.9, 61.2, 60.7, 61.8, 63.0, 57.7, 61.9, 63.9, 59.9, 60.6, 57.6, 57.4, 56.1, 58.7]
```

However, I decided to put this code in a function:

```
def LA_monthly_temp (month):
    LA_temp = list()
    for D in obj1:
       if D[0] == "Los Angeles" and D[1] == month and D[3] == 2014:
           LA_temp.append(D[4])
           return (statistics.mean(LA_temp))
```

IDEALLY, this function should return the mean of the temperatures in LA in January 2014. HOWEVER, this function only adds the temperature of the first day in January 2014 to the list, and stops.

Specifically

```
LA_monthly_temp(1)
```

would produce "55.6",  rather than "60.7" which is the right answer.

Why does my function run only once, even though my code is exactly the same?

Comment: You need to unindent `return (statistics.mean(LA_temp))` so that it's outside the `for` loop, you want it to run *after* the for loop has gone through all the entries.

Answer (score 4):

The indentation of the `return` statement is wrong.
It needs to be indented the same way as `for D in obj1:`

```
def LA_monthly_temp (month):
    LA_temp = list()
    for D in obj1:
        if D[0] == "Los Angeles" and D[1] == month and D[3] == 2014:
            LA_temp.append(D[4])
    return (statistics.mean(LA_temp))
```

This way, the `return` happens after the whole loop. In your case, `return` happens after the first item is read.